# why is $\sigma\tau\neq\tau\sigma$ in $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3] 2,\zeta_3)/\mathbb{Q})?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

**Theorem**: $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3] 2,\zeta_3)/\mathbb{Q}) =\langle\sigma, \tau\rangle\cong S_3$

---

**My question**: Why is  $\sigma\tau\neq\tau\sigma$ in $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3] 2,\zeta_3)/\mathbb{Q})?$

---

**My attempt**: I take $\sigma(\sqrt[3] 2, \zeta_3)=( \sqrt[3]2\zeta_3, \zeta_3)$ and $\tau(\sqrt[3] 2, \zeta_3)=(\sqrt[3] 2,\zeta_3^2)$

Then $\sigma\tau(\sqrt[3] 2, \zeta_3)=\sigma (\sqrt[3]2,\zeta_3^2)=( \sqrt[3]2\zeta_3, \zeta_3^2)\tag1$

similarly $ \tau \sigma(\sqrt[3] 2, \zeta_3) =\tau( \sqrt[3]2\zeta_3, \zeta_3)=( \sqrt[3]2\zeta_3, \zeta_3^2)\tag2$

From $(1)$ and $(2)  $

we  have $$\sigma\tau=\tau\sigma$$

This  implies $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3] 2,\zeta_3)/\mathbb{Q}$   is not isomorphic to  $S_3$

**Tell me where I'm wrong**?

Comment: One thing to note is that the Galois group of an irreducible polynomial of degree n (Here $x^3-2$) is always a (transitive) subgroup of $S_{n}$. If $\sigma$ and $tau$ commuted, you'd get $C_{6}$ which is not a subgroup of $S_{3}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well,

$$
\sigma\tau(\sqrt[3]2,\zeta_3)=\sigma(\sqrt[3]2,\zeta_3^2)=(\sqrt[3]2\zeta_3^\color{red}1,\zeta_3^2)
$$

while

$$
\tau\sigma(\sqrt[3]2,\zeta_3)=\tau(\sqrt[3]2\zeta_3,\zeta_3)=(\sqrt[3]2\zeta_3^\color{red}2,\zeta_3^2)\,.
$$

Comment: Im not getting  $\tau(\sqrt[3]2\zeta_3,\zeta_3)=(\sqrt[3]2\zeta_3^\color{red}2,\zeta_3^2)\,.
$  why not $\tau(\sqrt[3]2\zeta_3,\zeta_3)=(\sqrt[3]2\zeta_3^\color{red}1,\zeta_3^2)\,.
?$

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: @jasmine Since $\sqrt[3]{2}\zeta_3$ contains a $\zeta_3$ factor! It suffices to define every $\mathbb Q$-automorphisms action on the generating elements. However, the elements span $6$-dimensional vector space and every $\mathbb Q$-automorphism action on the basis elements is determined by how they are built of generating elements. Long story short, $$\tau(\sqrt[3]2\zeta_3)=\tau(\sqrt[3]2)\tau(\zeta_3)=\sqrt[3]2\zeta_3^2\,.$$